# How to identify AppClips is launched by appclip card or by the user by searching the appclip in spotlight

Tags: ios, swift, uiscenedelegate, nsuseractivity, apple-appclips

I am working on an appclip, when I scan a QR code, appclip card gets shown and on click of open appclips gets launched and I performed a booking flow. Now next time if user comes to appclips using QR code, then I want to show an alert to user, that there is a booking already, however if he simply searches by spotlight and opens the app then dont display any alert.

Upon my debugging I found no way to identify whether appclip got opened by appclip card or by spotlight search. Please help. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Add a URL query parameter to your appclip code.

Comment: @Paulw11 both during launch by app clip card and spotlight search, I am getting the same URL with same query parameters.

Comment: So launching from a spotlight search is launching with the query parameter you encoded into your app clip code?

Comment: Yes, I am getting with query parameters both cases - @Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Apple believes that launching from an app switcher is equivalent to launching through a card.

> If a user returns to a previously launched App Clip from the App Library or Spotlight, the App Clip uses the invocation URL that it previously used to launch the App Clip.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/app_clips/responding_to_invocations

I agree that this behavior is illogical and results in the app not working properly.  I also faced this problem, maybe you found a workaround?

Comment: Answer fields are for _answers_. Do not use them to address a question to the questioner.